# Help checking if an inequality holds

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, inequality

I have the following inequality derived from a convex pentagon of sides $a,b,c,d,e$ and inner angles $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta,\epsilon$ and I want to prove that is always false (all the variables are positive reals):

$$2\left(ab+bc+cd+de+ea\right)+ac+bd+ce+da+eb>a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}+d^{2}+e^{2}-$$

$$4\left(ea\cos\alpha+ab\cos\beta+bc\cos\gamma+cd\cos\delta+de\cos\epsilon\right)+$$

$$2(\sqrt{\left(a^{2}+e^{2}-2ae\cos\alpha\right)\left(c^{2}+d^{2}-2cd\cos\delta\right)}+\sqrt{\left(b^{2}+a^{2}-2ba\cos\beta\right)\left(d^{2}+e^{2}-2de\cos\epsilon\right)}+$$

$$\sqrt{\left(c^{2}+b^{2}-2cb\cos\gamma\right)\left(e^{2}+a^{2}-2ea\cos\alpha\right)}+\sqrt{\left(d^{2}+c^{2}-2dc\cos\delta\right)\left(a^{2}+b^{2}-2ab\cos\beta\right)}+\sqrt{\left(e^{2}+d^{2}-2ed\cos\epsilon\right)\left(b^{2}+c^{2}-2bc\cos\gamma\right)}$$

For a convex pentagon, we have that:

$$\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta,\epsilon<180º$$
$$\cos\alpha+\cos\beta+\cos\gamma+\cos\delta+\cos\epsilon\leq-\frac{1}{2}$$

What I have tried:

If $a=b=c=d=e$ and $\alpha=\beta=\gamma=\delta=\epsilon$ (regular pentagon), it can be simplified to:

$$15a^2>5a^2+30.9a^2+22a^2$$

$$15a^2>57.9a^2$$

Therefore, the inequality is false by far in this particular case.

If we consider $a=b=c=d=e$, the $2\left(ab+bc+cd+de+ea\right)+ac+bd+ce+da+eb>a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}+d^{2}+e^{2}$ part of the inequality turns into $15a^2>5a^2$, and the rearrangement inequality guarantees that the diference between both sides of the inequality (in this concrete part) reduces as difference between the values of $a,b,c,d,e$ increase, "playing" in favor of the falsehood of the inequality.

The fact that $\cos\alpha+\cos\beta+\cos\gamma+\cos\delta+\cos\epsilon\leq-\frac{1}{2}$  guarantees that $4\left(ea\cos\alpha+ab\cos\beta+bc\cos\gamma+cd\cos\delta+de\cos\epsilon\right)$ will be negative. Here there are two effects; on the one hand, as the difference between the values of $a,b,c,d,e$ increase, the expression decreases; other hand, when $\alpha=\beta=\gamma=\delta=\epsilon$, we have that  $\cos\alpha+\cos\beta+\cos\gamma+\cos\delta+\cos\epsilon<-\frac{3}{2}$, which is more than three times less than the upper bound derived for this sum; therefore, as the angles become different, it is expected that the expression will reduce towards the upper bound of $-\frac{1}{2}$. It would be interesting to bound which is the minimum value that this expression should have in terms of $ab+bc+cd+de+ea$.

Finally, it seems clear that the expressions in the roots will be always positive, and overall the whole expression involving the sum of roots should be positive enough to compensate the reduction in the value from the previous expression, but I find it difficult to handle. Any idea would be welcomed.

Thanks in advance for your help!